# Are MPTTs inefficient to scale?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, nosql, rdbms, mptt

I'm using the CakePHP ACLs that heavily rely on Modified Preordered Traversal Trees. We've been worried about how easy they are to scale.

Obviously insertions are going to quickly become expensive as more and more rows need to have their `lft` and `rght` columns updated.

Two things I *think* I am right in assuming:

1. The UPDATE queries themselves won't carry much weight since they'll remain the same regardless of DB size.
2. The database's read/write operations onto the actual filesystem obviously start to become more and more expensive.

Is there anything I've been missing out on? Thing is we're really considering moving to a NoSQL DB because of this and a few more things. Scared about doing this on Cake because it would mean using non-standard data sources.

Comment: How many rows are you talking about?  Sounds like maybe you should think about reworking your permissions.

Comment: The permissions by themselves aren't causing the problem, but if I have lots of objects on the system, they still need to keep getting inserted into the ACOs right?

Comment: Do you have billions of rows? Did you do any performance tests that make you worry? Are you running on a Pentium I box? How would NoSQL be of any help here?

Comment: Billions, no. Millions, easily. No. No, I'm more worried about disk I/O, not processing. No numbering read/writes for the nodes, and storing the tree as a graph directly? What'd you just do by asking me more questions and still not directing me towards any answer?

Comment: Angad - the permissions ARE the issue if you're storing them in a Tree w/ millions of rows that make you concerned about speed.

Comment: Oh I get you now! You're saying avoid using the Behaviour to auto-create the rows for each object, and instead of having object-level (fine-grain) permissions, have them at model level. I wanted to keep them fine-grain for future-proofing reasons, but I guess you can't have your cake and eat it too :)

Comment: It doesn't have to be all-or-nothing like that. I think you'll find you're setting current permissions based on a simple set of rules (e.g. "public documents can be edited by anyone"). Turn that into a data relationship ("Document belongsTo DocumentType") and set the ACL permission on the DocumentType "Public" row instead. Then the permissions cascade to your Documents, with the right model setup. You're still future-proof as you can override permissions at the Document level if you wish.